# How can I get an individual char from a string literal in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

How does one get an individual char from a char pointer?

Example snippet that I would want to get a char from:

```
char *name = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";
```

How could I get B? Would I just do:

```
char oneChar = name[*name+1];
```

I'm a little unclear as to how I can get an individual char from *name.

Would another possible solution be to create a new array:

```
char newArray[100];
newArray = *name;
```

Thank you for your help guys! The most important thing is to know how to get the individual char out of name.

The purpose of this is to pass the char through a function that will return another char that is an encrypted version of this, then I would concatenate that encrypted char to a new char array. So for example:

```
char a = getEncryptedChar(name[1]); //This won't work since name is a pointer.
char newEncryptedName[100] += a;
```

Sorry for any obscene errors, I'm relatively new to C, thank you for any help providing  me.

Comment: `word` is a char array. `"Hello"` is a literal, `word[0]` has a value of `'H'`. What are you converting to what?

Comment: `char individual_char = "Hello"[1];`.  Now `individual_char` has the value of `'e'`.

Comment: I'll edit my question accordingly @EugeneSh.

Comment: The second line of the code doesn't make any sense to me. Is @chux 's comment doing what you want?

Comment: You're asking for three completely different things here (get individual char, convert array to pointer, convert pointer to array). Which one do you actually need?

Comment: When declaring char *name; and then initializing name = "Hello"; the pointer is pointing to the first index to the char array. Looking at my second line of code I'm trying to get the pointer at the first index in word[] to convert that word into a string literal.

Comment: assuming local scope you will want to include a null char `{'h','e','l','l','e','\0'};`

Comment: @Miguel J. "...to convert that word into a string literal" can not be done.  Code can't change a variable like `word[]` into a string literal.  A "string literal"  like `"Hello"` is a piece of source code that does not exist like a changeable variable.  `char word[10] = "Hello"` will initialize `word` with `'H'`, `'e'`, etc. and _those_ values in `word[]` can change.  `"Hello"` can not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your code above is illegal as `word[0]` is a char (not a pointer) so `*word[0]` is an invalid expression.

If you'd like to get the address of a specific character in the char array then you can simply do `char *converted = &word[i]`, where `i` indicates index of the character you're interested in its address (i.e. `&word[0]` in your case above).

Comment: Ah yes I made appropriate fixes to word[]. Thank you!